# SQL Server CE query exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-ce

Might be an easy question, but I'm very new to ASP.net and I keep getting the exception

> *There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token
>   line offset = 142,Token in error =  ]*
>
> *Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.*
>
> *Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There was
>   an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset
>   = 142,Token in error =  ]*

All I'm trying to do is get my grid view to only display results that are similar to whatever the user puts in the text box.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string query = TextBox1.Text;
   string sql = "SELECT [Username], [Job Description] AS Job_Description, [Hours Worked] AS Hours_Worked, [Date], [ID] FROM [TimeData]"; // this one works fine 

   string sql2 = "SELECT [Username], [Job Description] AS Job_Description, [Hours Worked] AS Hours_Worked, [ID], [Date] FROM [TimeData] WHERE ([Username] == '" +query + "'";
   Response.Write("done");
   SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sql2;
}
```

I'm using a datasource from a local `.SDF` file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are open to SQL injection, so you need to use parameters in that second query. There are plenty of answers about that on SO. Also, your query is wrong. You can remove the `(` from your `WHERE` clause and it will be `=` not `==`.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into once I figure out how to update the selected attribute in the gridview .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a closing parentheses at the end of sql2

Comment: Yeah I had to remove the = and add a ). I feel dumb. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As @Adam states your are missing a closing parenthesis.  Also, change "==" to "=" for SQL.

However, adding the username (`query` var) directly into the SQL opens your appklication to a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) attack.  You should use SQL parameters, see the http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter example.